# Will it result in out of memory when I create an item object and add to tableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am learning to insert item to `tableWidget`. Below is the code comes from internet

```cpp
//void QTableWidget::setItem(int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem *item);
QString str = "test";
while(1){
  ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(str));
}
```

The `str` will changed periodically, so I call the above function periodically. I think it may result in out of memory when I run it for a long time, but in fact the heap memory does not increase with running time and keeps a low level.

So, how to explain the phenomenon? What's the reason in it?

Comment: Are you wondering about `str` or `new QTableWidgetItem(str)`?

Comment: When you add an item to a table, the table takes ownership of that item and maintains its deletion, when needed.

Comment: If you just need to change the text you can do that with `ui->tableWidget->item(0, 0)->setText(str)` -- assuming the item already exists of course.

Comment: I wondering about  ```new QTableWidgetItem(str)```, like that ```while(1){ ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(str)); }```